# fast computation of traiangular matrix with certain pattern

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering for a matrix with the following form.

\begin{bmatrix}p_0&0&0&0\\p_1&p_0&0&0\\p_2&p_1&p_0&0\\p_3&p_2&p_1&p_0\end{bmatrix}

Is there any trick to compute the product of this matrix and a vector with a complexity less than regular $\frac{N^2}{2}$?

Comment: Is there some relationship between the $p_k$?

Comment: Do you want $A \vec{x}$ or $\vec{x} A$?

Comment: @copper.hat: $p_k$ are not related

Comment: @gt6989b:I am interested in $Ax$

Comment: I can't imagine that you can improve on the stated complexity...

Comment: Such form of matrices is called Toeplitz matrix, so it is possible now to check weather there exists methods that fast perform toeplitz matrix-vector multiplication. This is an example http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node384.html hopefully this is useful for you